# iPhone tonepad functionality in two-way/conference calls

Tags: iphone, phone-call, dtmf

It's easy enough to, for example, make a call from an iPhone app and then use the comma pause character to send DTMF signals to navigate through a tonepad menu:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://somenumber,,1,,2"]];`

But it doesn't seem to work if you are already in a call, and want to place a second call. When I try this from the app with the code above, it dials `somenumber`but seems to ignore the `,,1,,2` completely. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing I discovered that iOS indeed ignores any instances of `,,1` etc, once you have established a phone call with the first party.